# Push & Pull objects out of array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, typescript

I have 2 types of Collections and I cannot get it to work on either, they are similar tho:

Coll-A:

```
{
    "_id": {...},
    "something that doesnt matter": {...},
    "var1": {
        "var2": [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}],
        "var3": [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
    },
    "something that doesnt matter": {...}
}
```

I am trying to push and pull objects in and out of the var2 array,
I have tried multiple things like:

```
await db.collection("coll").findOneAndUpdate(
    { var1: { $exists: true } },
    { $push: { var1: { var2: object} } }
);
```

But then it says var1 is not an array, and when I tried it with pull it emptied my whole collection xD
For pulling, there is a unique ID in each object which I know that has to be removed.

Coll-B:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {...},
        "uniqueId": "01",
        "settings": {
            "var1": {
                "var2": [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}],
                "var3": {...}
            },
            "var3": [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
        },
        "something that doesnt matter": {...}
    },
    {
        "_id": {...},
        "uniqueId": "02",
        "settings": {
            "var1": {
                "var2": [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}],
                "var3": {...}
            },
            "var3": [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
        },
        "something that doesnt matter": {...}
    }
]
```

Coll-B is a little different is has multiple objects at the start, which all have a unique ID tho, and in the var2 array where we need to Push and Pull all objects have unique ids too.

If anyone has ideas on how we can make this work let us know! Because right now we are `$set` -ing the whole array over again, and when multiple are running at once only the last one updates, so I really need to work with push and pull.

Comment: Try the dot(.) notation to reach the array field you want to push/pull on Example: `{ $push: { "var1.var2": { object } } }` OR `{ $pull: { "var1.var2": { object } } }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try the dot(.) notation to reach the array field you want to push/pull
> on Example: { $push: { "var1.var2": { object } } } OR { $pull: {
> "var1.var2": { object } } }. – @ambianBeing

Yes thank you that helped I now use:

for updating:

```
let index = `settings.var1.var2.${id}`;

coll.findOneAndUpdate(
    { uniqueId: uId },
    { $set: { [index]: follows[id] } }
);
```

for pushing:

```
coll.findOneAndUpdate(
    { uniqueId: uId },
    {
        $push: {
            "settings.var1.var2": newObject
        }
    }
);
```

for pulling:

```
let index = `settings.var1.var2.${id}`;

await coll.findOneAndUpdate(
    { uniqueId: uId },
    { $unset: { [index]: 1 } }
);

await coll.findOneAndUpdate(
    { uniqueId: uId },
    {
        $pull: {
            "settings.var1.var2": null
        }
    }
);
```